# How to get programmatically the list of apps which can display over other apps?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get the list of apps that can display over other apps. Like on the screenshot, but programmatically:
[image: List of apps with Display over other apps permission]

I try to get all installed packages

`val pkgs = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)`

Packages in `pkgs`  have requestedPermissions - the list of permissions requested in the manifest.

Using this list, I am filtering packages with `"android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"` permission.
But the apps with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and the list on the screenshot are not equal.

Is there any way to get this list programmatically?

Comment: "But apps with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and list on screenshot not equal." -- what specifically are the differences? Your approach seems sound. Have you tried this on other devices besides the one that you used for the screenshot?

Comment: if you want to show a list of apps in your app using dialog then this is the valid point otherwise you are not properly using android services, so please make sure you're requirements are clear.

Comment: Thank you for you answers.
@CommonsWare , I checked lists again. List of SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW  apps have 52 element, and list from screenshot have 35 element. But I noticed that the first list contain all element from the second. Looks like the frist list it is the second list + some system apps. And it is probably what I need.

Comment: But there still one porblem. 
When i check is permission is available with requestedPermissionsFlags field in package - I got wrong result.
For exapmle, AliExpress app don,t have permision, and requestedPermissionsFlags field for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW   show the same. When I allow permission in settings, and check it in my app again, requestedPermissionsFlags field still show that permission not allowed. 
That why i thought that it was wrong way.

Comment: You might want to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question with a more complete [mcve]. Basically, show how you are getting the results in your most recent comment. Perhaps we will see something that explains those results.